# Bind a ListBox or ItemsControl inside a Custom Button Control

Tags: listbox, controls, relativesource, templatebinding

Hi I am new to XAML and I am trying to build a custom toggle button control. My control has the following code which does not give any compile or run time error but does not display the data. I kept getting error when I tried to do regular templatebinding, after research I found that I need to use Relative Source. But cant get the list to populate. Can someone guide on what I am doing wrong? Or if there is a better way to do this?

Objective: Build a checkable control which has a list control.

**XAML Generic.xml:** (this code is inside a togglebutton controltemplate)

```
    <ListBox BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" 
ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=MyRoutes}">
<!--<ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
<Binding Mode="TwoWay" Path="MyRoutes">
<Binding.RelativeSource>
<RelativeSource Mode="TemplatedParent"/>
</Binding.RelativeSource>
</Binding>
</ItemsControl.ItemsSource>-->
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<StackPanel>
<!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Value}"></TextBlock>-->
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"></TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**Code Behind PlainToggleButton.cs:**

```
public string[] MyRoutes
    {
        get { return (string[])GetValue(MyRoutesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyRoutesProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyRoutes.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyRoutesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyRoutes", typeof(string[]), typeof(PlainToggleButton), new PropertyMetadata(OnMyRoutesChanged));

    private static void OnMyRoutesChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        return;
    }
```

**Code MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<local:PlainToggleButton Grid.Row="1" MyRoutes="{Binding MyRoutes}">            
    </local:PlainToggleButton>
```

Comment: Silly me!! Creating a DataBound control and forgetting to set its context. Enjoying the amazing power of WPF and Databinding :)